# Mimic another Ruby class so the object passes the === type check

Tags: ruby, class, types, mocking

I want to create an object that acts as a specific class, such as Fixnum, but isn't an instance of that class nor its subclasses.

There are various use-cases for this. In the Fixnum case, I want to define a more specific integer type that is essentially a Fixnum but implements some extra logic, too. I can't subclass Fixnum itself because immediate types such as Fixnum and Symbol can't be subclassed.

Another use-case is mocking in automated tests: sometimes you want to create an object that acts like a certain class (usually a model instance) but is for technical reasons not an instance of that exact class.

Here's how to create a specific integer type that delegates all methods to an internally stored fixnum:

```
require 'delegate'
require 'forwardable'

# integer representing a page number
class PageNumber < DelegateClass(Integer)
  extend Forwardable

  def initialize(value, name)
    @name = name
    super(value)
  end

  def inspect
    "#{@name} #{to_i}"
  end

  alias_method :to_i, :__getobj__
  def_delegators :to_i, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?
end
```

This object can pass `is_a?` and similar checks:

```
page = PageNumber.new(1, "page")
page.is_a? Fixnum  #=> true
```

But nothing I do can make it pass the [`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html#M000203) type check:

```
# my problem:
Fixnum === page    #=> false
```

The fact that my object fails this check is very unfortunate, since the `===` method is used internally in `case` statements:

```
case page
when Fixnum
  # it will never get here
when String
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

My question is how can I create a mock type that passes the `===` check *without* augmenting the `===` methods on built-in classes?

Comment: Note: I'm asking about MRI here. Different Ruby implementations have `===` implemented differently so the solution for one might not work in others.

Comment: "I can't subclass Fixnum itself because immediate types such as Fixnum and Symbol can't be subclassed." Why is that? I just tried to subclass Fixnum and it worked in 1.8.7 and 1.9.2

Comment: @jigfox, now try to do `Mynum.new` and watch it to fail. Immediate types are represented internally in a way which prevents subclasses of them being usable; look at [these checks](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/include/ruby/ruby.h#322), for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hackish solution that I warned against in my question:

```
Fixnum === page  #=> false

Numeric.extend Module.new {
  def ===(obj)
    obj.instance_of?(PageNumber) or super
  end
}

Fixnum === page  #=> true
```

It solves the problem but raises a question is it safe to do? I can't think of any drawbacks of this method from the top of my mind but since we're messing with a very important method here it might not be something we'd want to do.

Comment: Actually, you don't. The _important_ method is the one in C API, and it is indeed used hundreds of times (well... 208 times, to be precise) internally. What you are redefining is a case comparison method; the only thing you may break is, well, case comparison. This solution looks perfectly fine for me. Talking about other implementations, I think that JRuby works roughly the same way, but for Rubinius you should check everything carefully.

Answer (score 15):

If we are speaking about the MRI<sup>1</sup>, the answer is simple: you cannot.

The `Module#===` method is effectively an [alias](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/object.c#1306) of [`rb_obj_is_kind_of`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/object.c#481) C API method. The implementation of latter is so short that I will paste it here:

```
VALUE
rb_obj_is_kind_of(VALUE obj, VALUE c)
{
    VALUE cl = CLASS_OF(obj);

    /* Type checking of `c' omitted */

    while (cl) {
    if (cl == c || RCLASS_M_TBL(cl) == RCLASS_M_TBL(c))
        return Qtrue;
    cl = RCLASS_SUPER(cl);
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

As you can see, this method traverses the ancestors of the object being examined, and compares them in two ways: first, it checks if the ancestor is the same as the module which was passed, and then, it checks if they have same method table.

The latter check is required because included modules in Ruby are seemingly inserted in the inheritance chain, but as one module may be included in several other ones, it's not the real module which is inserted into the chain, but a proxy object, which has its constant and method tables pointing to the original module.

For example, let's look at Object's ancestors:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > Object.ancestors
 => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > Object.ancestors.map { |mod| Object.new.is_a? mod }
 => [true, true, true]
```

Here, the `Object` and `BasicObject` will be successfully compared by the first check, and `Kernel` by the second one.

Even if you'll try to make (with a C extension) a proxy object which will try to trick the `rb_obj_is_kind_of` method, it will need to have the same method table as a real `Fixnum`, which would effectively include all `Fixnum`'s methods.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've investigated the internals for Ruby 1.9, but they behave exactly same way in 1.8.

Comment: Great answer. I would appreciate if you checked out my own answer and add your comments to it.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right answer, because Fixnum doesn't use `Module.===`, but `Fixnum.===`. There is a very specific override in `numeric.c`.

Comment: @John, can you point me to that method? I can only see `Fixnum#===`. Moreover, it looks like you overlook how `case` actually works... check [this](http://pastebin.com/wZnYVzRB) snippet out.

Comment: @whitequark: I'm referring to the `fix_equal` method at https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L2761, which I believe is used since there is an `rb_define_method` for it: `rb_define_method(rb_cFixnum, "===", fix_equal, 1);`. Also, the link you provided doesn't work for me.

Comment: @John, the link works for me, but here is the [same snippet on another pastebin site](http://dpaste.com/hold/588956/), anyway. This method isn't used; it is defined for Fixnum instances, not the class itself. I hope my code will explain what you are misunderstanding.

Comment: @whitequark: I appreciate your in-depth research and answers on this issue. However, I marked my own answer as accepted because it provides a solution for this issue (however hackish it might seem) which might be helpful to other readers.

Comment: @mislav, no problem, but then you really should reformulate your question (i.e. "what's the best way, without hacking the Module#=== method when it is possible" or something similar). I won't take any offence if you will not accept my answer (hey, you're _that Mislav_ everyone knows about, anyway), but the question should really be consistent with the answer. I'll adjust mine accordingly.